# Multiple taps in tap layout in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

I am a beginner to android studio,  Like WhatsApp, I like to have different taps (Chat, call, status) for my app. I know to make that using view pager and page Adapter this can be done, but here I like to have at least 10 tabs like the one in YouTube app (all, recently added, our subscriptions etc.)  Can any one help me in creating such sort  of scrolling tabs.

Answer (score 1):

I found out, there is an the inbuilt code ,  app:tabMode="scrollable" , served my purpose

Answer (score 1):

Saved my life by `app:tabMode="scrollable"` or `app:tabMode="auto"` will helpful, whether scrolling functionality can be enabled through java coding other than XML.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I was also looking for the solution to the same problem. I think `app:tabMode="auto"` will also be helpful.